# Yii2 fork: dev-custom exists as yiisoft/yii2 but these are rejected by your constraint

Tags: github, yii2, composer-php, fork

I'm trying to use my forked version of [yiisoft/yii2](https://github.com/david-it/yii2) in an installation of [yii2-app-advanced](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced).

I've followed [this wiki](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/673/using-your-own-forked-version-of-extensions-with-composer).

I have created a branch named `custom` and pushed it to my yii2 fork.

In the composer.json of my fork I have the following (does it matter?):

```
...
"extra": {
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-custom": "2.0.x-dev"
    }
...
```

Then in my `yii2-app-advanced` installation I have the following `composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",

    ...

    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/david-it/yii2"
        }        
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "dev-custom",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0 || ~2.1.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4": "~2.0.6"
    },

    ...

}
```

When I run `composer update` I get the following error:

```
Problem 1
    - The requested package yiisoft/yii2 dev-custom exists as yiisoft/yii2[2.0.0, 2.0.0-alpha, 2.0.0-beta, 2.0.0-rc, 2.0.1, 2.0.10, 2.0.11, 2.0.11.1, 2.0.11.2, 2.0.12, 2.0.12.1, 2.0.12.2, 2.0.13, 2.0.13.1, 2.0.13.2, 2.0.13.3, 2.0.14, 2.0.14.1, 2.0.14.2, 2.0.15, 2.0.15.1, 2.0.16, 2.0.16.1, 2.0.17, 2.0.18, 2.0.19, 2.0.2, 2.0.20, 2.0.21, 2.0.22, 2.0.23, 2.0.24, 2.0.25, 2.0.26, 2.0.27, 2.0.28, 2.0.29, 2.0.3, 2.0.30, 2.0.31, 2.0.32, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, 2.0.9, 2.1.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev, dev-master, 2.0.x-dev] but these are rejected by your constraint.
```

The command `composer why-not yiisoft/yii2 dev-custom` (if it is any useful here) shows this:

```
yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4   2.0.8   requires  yiisoft/yii2 (~2.0)     
yiisoft/yii2-debug        2.1.13  requires  yiisoft/yii2 (~2.0.13)  
yiisoft/yii2-faker        2.0.4   requires  yiisoft/yii2 (~2.0.0)   
yiisoft/yii2-gii          2.1.4   requires  yiisoft/yii2 (~2.0.14)  
yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer  2.1.2   requires  yiisoft/yii2 (>=2.0.4)
```

I'm not sure what I am missing. I've looked around including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39974833/composer-the-requested-package-exists-as-but-these-are-rejected-by-your-constr) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45435583/composer-requested-package-0-0-9-exists-as-0-0-5-0-0-6-but-these-are-rejec) questions but with no luck.

**EDIT 1**

Composer 1.9.3 (2020-02-04 12:58:49) with PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 on Linux / 4.15.0-91-generic

**EDIT 2**

Selecting `dev-master` as required works but the original files are downloaded (not the ones in the fork).

```
"require": {
        ...
        "yiisoft/yii2": "dev-master",
        ...
}
```

I also tried all the tips from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41471934/1630538) with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you have the `custom` branch. You need to create a branch named `dev-custom` in this situation, use the same branch name in `require` section of your composer.json file.

> Your custom branch name *must be prefixed with dev-*.

Comment: I tried, renaming the branch both locally and online to `dev-custom` but I get the same error.
Plus, according to the [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository) "In composer.json, you should prefix your custom branch name with `dev-`" so to my understanding the branch name should be `custom` and its reference in composer.json should be `dev-custom `, as pointed out also here [https://stackoverflow.com/a/49562302/1630538](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49562302/1630538).

Comment: I confirm that this is not the right answer. The branch `custom` in composer needs to be referenced as `dev-custom`.

Answer (score 0):

After long hours of trial-and-error I've found two working solutions.

**Solution 1** (With the help of [Yii2 forum](https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/composer-use-fork-of-yiisoft-yii2-into-installation-of-yii2-app-advanced/129028))

The branch apparently is considered "unstable", so you need to specify `@dev` to make composer work fine:

```
"require": {
        ...
        "yiisoft/yii2": "dev-master@dev",
        ...
}
```

**Solution 2**

In the `composer.json` of my fork I've added an alias pointing to the branch:

```
"extra": {
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.0.x-dev",
        "dev-custom": "2.0.n-dev"
    }
}
```

Where `n` is just number (it should be unique among the versions available, I guess).

Then in the `composer.json` of my project I used `"yiisoft/yii2": "2.0.n.x-dev"`.

I'm not quite sure why I have to use `"2.0.n.x-dev"` instead of `"2.0.n-dev"`. A possible explanation is [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#branches).